# How to convert multidimensional array into HTML list with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this multidimensional (?) array:

```
LANGUAGES = [
  ['English', 'en'],
  ['Deutsch', 'de']
]
```

How can I convert this into a list of links?

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/en/">English</a></li>
  <li><a href="/de/">Deutsch</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using ERB or HAML or a different templater, or do you want only Ruby code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
LANGUAGES = [
  ['English', 'en'],
  ['Deutsch', 'de']
]

# in view, erb used
<ul>
  <% LANGUAGES.each do |name, short_name| %>
    <li><%= link_to name, "/#{short_name}/" %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

If you have defined the constant in a specific Model, let's say the User model, you can call it like this:

```
<% User::LANGUAGES.each do #[...] %>
```